# How to get POST var in ASP.NET when using ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I send ajax request using this code:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/Home/ShowStadium",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "text",
  type: "POST",
  data: Club,
  success: function (data) {
        $(".right-content").html(data);
          },
  error: function (xhr, textStatus) {
         alert([xhr.status, textStatus]);
        }

  });
```

In HomeController i have this function:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ShowStadium(){

            if (Request.Form["Club"] == "Some text to compare")
            {
                return Content("First variant");
            }
            else
            {
                return Content("Second variant");
            }

        }
```

But i can't get *data* sent by ajax to compare it. ***Request.Form["Club"]*** - not working!

Comment: What is `Club` in `data: Club,`? Your should add a parameter to you method `public ActionResult ShowStadium(string Club) {...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use as

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/Home/ShowStadium",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "text",
  type: "POST",
  data: {club:Club},
  success: function (data) {
        $(".right-content").html(data);
          },
  error: function (xhr, textStatus) {
         alert([xhr.status, textStatus]);
        }

  });
```

In HomeController i have this function:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ShowStadium(string club){

            if (club == "Some text to compare")
            {
                return Content("First variant");
            }
            else
            {
                return Content("Second variant");
            }

        }
```

Comment: I tried this way , but I getting "error 500" from ajax whit this code.

Comment: try after removing datatype

Comment: try removing **content-type** and set **datatype:json**

Comment: Issue is to remove content-type end retain dataType: text